# $\operatorname{deg}(f+g) \leq \max (\operatorname{deg} f, \operatorname{deg} g)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> Show that $\operatorname{deg}(f \cdot g)=\operatorname{deg} f+\operatorname{deg} g$ and $\operatorname{deg}(f+g) \leq \max (\operatorname{deg} f, \operatorname{deg} g)$.

---

Shouldn't $\operatorname{deg}(f+g)$ be equal to $\max (\operatorname{deg} f, \operatorname{deg} g)$, as we are multiplying both the polynomials? Please help as I can't figure out ehy it should be true.

Comment: $ \ f + g \ $ means we are _adding_ the polynomials;  $ \ f·g \ $ means we are multiplying them.

Comment: it's possible highest order terms are same degree and opposite signs.

Answer (score 3):

If $\deg f \neq \deg g$ then $\deg(f + g) = \max\{\deg f, \deg g\}$ but if $\deg f = \deg g$ then $\deg(f + g)$ can be any possible degree $\le \max\{\deg f, \deg g\}$.

This is because if $\deg f = \deg g = n$ and $f(x) = x^n + f_1(x)$ and $g(x) = -x^n + g_1(x)$ then

$$f(x) + g(x) = (x^n + f_1(x)) + (-x^n + g_1(x)) = f_1(x) + g_1(x).$$

And here the degree of $f_1 + g_1$ can be anything.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you meant to write "... as we are *adding* both polynomials", the inequality is there because the leading terms (and possibly other terms too) might be opposites of one another.

A quick example: $f(x) = 3x^2 + 5x - 2$ and $g(x) = -3x^2 - 2x + 1$. Then,
$$
(f+g)(x) = f(x) + g(x) = 3x - 1. 
$$
Clearly,
$$
\deg(f+g) = 1 < 2 = \max(2, 2) = \max(\deg f, \deg g). 
$$

---

By the way, a similar issue arises if you are considering polynomials with coefficients from a ring with zero divisors, such as $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, in which $2 \cdot 3 = 0$. The more general property that still holds is
$$
\deg(f \cdot g) \leq \deg f + \deg g
$$
Assuming that your coefficients are in an *integral domain* (such as $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, or $\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$ for $p$ a prime), then the degree function behaves just like the logarithm:
$$
\deg(f \cdot g) = \deg f + \deg g
$$